# Может ли слово "вместилище" использоваться с предлогом "для"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Например:
Храм - вместилище для длинной проповеди и молитвы.
Спасибо заранее!
И ещё хотелось бы разобраться (простите, далее последует немного странное предложение, но такая задумка):
вместилище (для?) длинной проповеди и пожара, которого (который) не видно (не виден).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После слова возможны родительный падеж и предлог:

вместилище
чего и для чего.

Вместилище воды. Вместилище для зерна.

Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь.

Вместилище (для) длинной проповеди и пожара, которого не видно.
Вместилище длинной проповеди и невидимого пожара.